# how to calculate student score and class average from a T/F exam in R

Tags: r

I have a data table that looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIKPM.png

```
df <- data.frame(id = c('Student 1', 'Student 2', 'Student 3', 'Student 4'), 
                 question1 = c(1, 2, 1, 2), 
                 qusetion2 = c(2, 2, 1, 1), 
                 question3 = c(1, 1, 2, 2), 
                 question4 = c(2, 1, 2, 1))
```

where 1 = True and 2 = False. I want to calculate each student's score such that their answer choices (1 or 2) matches the right answer choices (1 or 2). Then after that, I want to calculate the class average

Comment: so and() student answer with the correct result then sum for the total.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? You can calculate the class average by `sum(df.longer$right.answers)/total questions`

```
student.name <- c("student1", "student2", "student3", "student4")
Question1 <- c(1,2,1,2)
Question2 <- c(2,2,1,1)
Question3 <- c(1,1,2,2)
Question4 <- c(2,1,2,1)

df <- data.frame(student.name, Question1, Question2, Question3, Question4)

df.longer <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("Question"), names_to = "Question.id", values_to = "T/F" ) %>% 
  group_by(student.name) %>% 
  summarise(right.answers = length(`T/F`[`T/F` == 1]))
```

[image]